# socket send throws timeout error

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket

I have a  proxy client between two servers. The main server S1 is on the internet. The proxy client and the second server S2 sit in the same intranet. I have the following code (parts left out for simplicity) which is responsible for forwarding data coming from S2 'as is' to S1:

```
fsctimeout = 0.01

function send_data(sock, data, i, l)
    local p,err,q = sock:send(data, i, l)
    if(err == "timeout" and q ~= l) then
        fsctimeout = fsctimeout * 2
        sock:settimeout(fsctimeout)
        send_data(sock, data, q + 1, l)
        fsctimeout = fsctimeout / 2
        sock:settimeout(fsctimeout)
    end
end

while not e do

rect, _, st = socket.select({csc, fsc}, nil, .01) --csc is S1, fsc is S2 sockets.

    if(rect[fsc] ~= nil and csc ~= nil) then
        local data, err, part = fsc:receive(8192)
        if(data ~= nil) then
            send_data(csc, data, 1, data:len())
            totalBytesFromFP = totalBytesFromFP + data:len()
        end
        if(part ~= nil) then
            send_data(csc, part, 1, part:len())
            totalBytesFromFP = totalBytesFromFP + part:len()
        end
    end
 end
```

I wrote the `send_data` function so that if a send timeouts, it will double the socket timeout and try again. But now sometimes the programs gets stuck inside the `send_data` function without being successful in sending data. What can I do here? (I am testing trying to send a 1MB file, for small amounts of data this problem doesn't seem to be happenning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change timeout for the first time only after you get "timeout" error, but it never happens because by default `send` is blocking (so it will never times out).

Just add `csc:settimeout(fsctimeout)` before your loop.